# document.documentElement.scrollTop condition

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, addeventlistener, eventhandler

trying to understand the **first part** of the conditional statement in this code

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",function(event){
     if(document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop >= scrollDistance){
        animatePoints();
```

the second part says, *if a number of pixels you have scrolled from the top of the body is greater than or equates to the point where I want my animation to start, then call the function*
in my mind, that would work for any possible scenario

**I don't understand the first conditional** (and I have tried messing around with it in the console)

`console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop)` always returns 0.
my understanding is that this is because you are never scrolling the root element `<html>` so it will always return at 0.

if this is true then this first condition is always met and should fire the animatepoints function (yet it isn't)

Comment: if document.documentElement.scrollTop is always 0 then the first condition will be false not true

Comment: very helpful if you could elaborate on what the first condition actually means in plain english, thank you

Comment: It means: IF the `scrollTop` property of the `documentElement` isn't 0, `false`, `undefined`, `null` or `''` OR the `scrollTop` property of the `body` element is greater or equal the scroll distance THEN call the method `animatePoints`.

Comment: @cyrix thank you! i didn't understand that 0==false in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if `document.documentElement.scrollTop` isn't 0, false, undefined, null or '' it runs the second statement which is `document.body.scrollTop >= scrollDistance`.